# Session NullReferenceException caused by hybrid use of RazorPage and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, razor-pages

This question is solved, but just for my record and hope would solve someone else (Although the error is by careless). I forgot to delete code from a RazorPage template of Index.cshtml used in a MVC project. I even forgot why it is there.
But if someone could explain the detail cause of the error would be appreciated.
Firstly, I had this error in the following code.

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=TestMVCWebApp001.Views
  StackTrace:
   at TestMVCWebApp001.Views.Home.Views_Home_Index.<ExecuteAsync>d__18.MoveNext() in C:\Users\user\source\repos\TestMVCWebApp001\TestMVCWebApp001\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:line 220
```

```
//Index.cshtml
@page
@model TestMVCWebApp001.Models.DashboardPage
<input type="hidden" name="sessionId" id="sessionId" value=@ViewData["sessionId"] />
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete the @page from the code would solve the problem.
Because @page would be treated as a Razor Page instead of a regular view.